# Error occured by chrome

Tags: permissions, google-chrome, compiling

When I open installed google chrome

```
google-chrome-stable
```

Then it shows :

```
[0503/011955.057655:ERROR:nss_util.cc(94)] Failed to create /home/abhi/.pki/nssdb directory.
[0503/011955.102455:ERROR:nss_util.cc(94)] Failed to create /home/abhi/.pki/nssdb directory.
[8512:8549:0503/011955.251332:ERROR:nss_util.cc(94)] Failed to create /home/abhi/.pki/nssdb directory.
[8512:8512:0503/011955.355846:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(416)] readlink failed: Permission denied
[8512:8512:0503/011955.355902:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(252)] readlink(/home/abhi/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied
[8512:8512:0503/011955.355935:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(252)] readlink(/home/abhi/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied
[8512:8512:0503/011955.355945:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(276)] Failed to create /home/abhi/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock: Permission denied
[8512:8512:0503/011955.355961:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(416)] readlink failed: Permission denied
[8512:8512:0503/011955.355972:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(252)] readlink(/home/abhi/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied
[8512:8512:0503/011955.356132:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1571)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

Please suggest me what problem I'm doing   .

Answer (score 1):

Seems you don't have write access to the `~/.config` path.

run:

```
mv ~/.pki{,.bk}
chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.config
```

if you still got problem:

```
chown -R 775 ~/.config
```

If you get any permission error while running these commands, run them as root with `sudo`.